# Testing rest api with Kotlin and JUnit 5

Tags: rest, api, kotlin, junit5

I am doing the testicles from my Rest API, but I am not able to test the "insert" of the controller.

My controller

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/api/clients/lp"])
    override fun insert(@Valid @RequestBody model: LegalPersonModel): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        service.insert(service.modelToEntity(model))
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }
```

My Test

```
val lp = LegalPerson(1L, 1L, true, "Test Fantasy", "Test LTDA",
            "test@com", "40.492.967/0001-52", "Test S", "Test M",
            LocalDate.of(2017, 10, 21), 1L, listOf(1L, 22L))
@Test
    fun insert() {
        Mockito.doReturn(lp).`when`(service)!!.insert(lp)
        mockMvc?.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/clients/lp")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .contentType(ObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule()).let {
                    it.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
                    it.writeValueAsString(lp)
                }))
                ?.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated)
                ?.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
    }
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "{"id":1,"companyId":1,"active":true,"tradeName":"Test Fantasy","companyName":"Test LTDA","email":"test@com","cnpj":"40.492.967/0001-52","stateRegistration":"Test S","municipalRegistration":"Test M","openingDate":"2017-10-21","address":1,"phones":[1,22]}": Invalid token character '{' in token "{"id":1,"companyId":1,"active":true,"tradeName":"Test Fantasy","companyName":"Test LTDA","email":"test@com","cnpj":"40.492.967"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write `content` instead of `contentType` on the line with the `ObjectMapper`.